# Rawset function in lua

Tags: lua

Rawset function in lua generally is passed table, index and value but I came across this code:

```
rawset(tbl,name,{})
```

and

```
rawset(tbl,name, function() end)
```

Rawset function returns a table, so what does it mean to have a table or function in rawset function in place for value ?

Comment: `rawset(tbl, name, {})` is equivalent to `tbl.name = {}`, provided that no metatable is associated with the table. Tables in Lua can hold multiple type values at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reference manual:

> `rawset (table, index, value)`: Sets the real value of table[index] to value, without invoking any metamethod. table must be a table, index any value different from nil, and value any Lua value.

What this means:

- *table's metatable is not used*: that's why it is "raw" set, the field is added directly; without raw, the table's metatable will be used to handle the "set" action;
- *index any value different from nil*: in Lua, this really means *any* type of Lua object other than nil: a number, a function, another table, etc (Lua ref manual lists all types);
- *value any Lua value*: same as previous, but can even be nil: if set to nil, effectively removes item from table.

So index being name just indicates the table is an associative array (unless name is a number but that would be misleading), in first case the associated value is another table, in the second case it is a Lua function.

Answer (score 4):

Lua tables can hold values of all types, including tables and functions, and they can be heterogeneous: not all values need to be of the same type.

See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1.